# Use Tags In Vim For Notes

Tags: vim, tags

**Backstory:** So there is all these notes app like Evernote Onenote... but I do not want to be locked into a system and only are going to use my laptop. So I thought why not use vim to edit markdown files which are saved in a Dropbox folder. And it would be nice to have tags working on it as well but there are a few problems with tags, I can't easily rename them.

**Problem:** How can I change tags and files without changing the tag location? Eg a tag called `flying potato project` and I want to rename it to `potato express` and change the file from `potato-idea.md` to `potato-idea-for-ever.md` but still keeping the tag location.

Maybe something with ids? Eg the tag for the text about potato express could be `@253`

**INFO EDIT:**
If you don't know what vim tags is then have a look at this website http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags

**Edit**:
This post has also been posted here
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/how-to-use-tags-in-vim-for-notes and
https://superuser.com/questions/1279464/how-to-use-tags-in-vim-for-notes

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. This question amounts to asking "can you design a note system for me with these loose requirements?"

Comment: @DanLowe, I'm only asking about the tags. The backstory is just to tell for what purpose I'm going to use the tags. Have you read the problem part?

Comment: I see someone else has voted to close as "unclear what you are asking." I would agree with that as well - perhaps you can be more specific? It's not clear to me what approach you are using, in order to suggest a way to improve it. Vim has no notion of tags in files that I know of, for instance, at least not outside of its help subsystem.

Comment: @DanLowe, This is so cool! You are going to learn something new today. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags

Comment: You seem to have no real response to this; you might have better luck if you ask on the vi/vim site - https://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks a lot. Can you see what my problem is? Just added the question https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/how-to-use-tags-in-vim-for-notes